# Pythonic way of building up a numpy array without having to explicitely handle the first assignment?

Tags: python, numpy

I find myself encountering this sort of coding pattern quite often:

```
matrices = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
block = np.array([])
for idx, M in enumerate(matrices):
    print(M.shape)
    if idx == 0:
        block = M
    else:
        block = np.dstack((block, M))
```

This is just an example, I'm aware that in this case I could just do `block = matrices`. Is there a better way of doing this without having to handle the

```
if idx == 0:
    block = M
```

case?

Comment: Are you aware that currently, you are sort of transposing the matrix?

Comment: If nothing else works, you could make it shorter as just `block = np.dstack((block, M)) if idx else M`

Comment: @tobias_k, how am I transposing the matrix exactly? I don't mean to be.

Comment: Just do `print(matrices)` and `print(block)` to see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't accumulate the arrays with `dstack` (or any of the concatenate variantes) - use list append

```
block = []
for idx, M in enumerate(matrices):
    block.append(M)
```

then 'stack' them after

```
block = np.dstack(block)   # concatenate(block, axis=2)
```

This is faster, and avoids this initialization awkwardness.